# Using jQuery to Clone Multiple Form Elements Within Separate Divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, clone

I am using the following script to clone a div with form elements inside; however, it currently adding sequential numbers (1, 2, 3) to the container div id correctly, but then is adding a "name2" and "name3" to the sub-divs in the clone, instead of to the actual form elements.

Example of problem:

```
<div class="clonedInput" id="container1">
    <div>First Name:
        <input type="text" id="first_name1" name="first_name1">
    </div>
    <div>Last Name:
        <input type="text" id="last_name1" name="last_name1">
    </div>
    <div>Phone:
        <input type="text" id="phone1" name="phone1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clonedInput" id="container2">
    <div id="name2" name="name2">First Name:
        <input type="text" id="first_name1" name="first_name1">
    </div>
    <div>Last Name:
        <input type="text" id="last_name1" name="last_name1">
    </div>
    <div>Phone:
        <input type="text" id="phone1" name="phone1">
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clonedInput" id="container3">
    <div id="name3" name="name3">First Name:
        <input type="text" id="first_name1" name="first_name1">
    </div>
    <div>Last Name:
        <input type="text" id="last_name1" name="last_name1">
    </div>
    <div>Phone:
        <input type="text" id="phone1" name="phone1">
    </div>
</div>
```

Full code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery( function ( $ ) {
    $( '#btnAdd' ).click( function() {
        var num = $( '.clonedInput' ).length;      // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        var newNum  = new Number( num + 1 );        // the numeric ID of the new input field being added
        var newElem = $( '#container' + num ).clone().attr( 'id', 'container' + newNum );

        newElem.children( ':first' ).attr( 'id', 'name' + newNum ).attr( 'name', 'name' + newNum );
        $( '#container' + num ).after( newElem );
        $( '#btnDel' ).attr( 'disabled', false );
        if ( newNum == 25 )
            $( '#btnAdd' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    });

    $( '#btnDel' ).click( function() {
        var num = $( '.clonedInput' ).length;      // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
        $( '#container' + num ).remove();              // remove the last element
        $( '#btnAdd' ).attr( 'disabled', false );  // enable the "add" button

        // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
        if ( num-1 == 1 )
            $( '#btnDel' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
    });

    $( '#btnDel' ).attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
});
        </script>
</head>

<body>
<form id="myForm">
    <div id="container1" class="clonedInput"> 
        <div>
        First Name:
        <input type="text" name="first_name1" id="first_name1">
        </div>
        <div>
        Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="last_name1" id="last_name1">
        </div>
        <div>
        Phone:
        <input type="text" name="phone1" id="phone1">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="add another name" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDel" value="remove name" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you're only changing first child with `newElem.children( ':first' )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line here:

```
newElem.children( ':first' ).attr( 'id', 'name' + newNum ).attr( 'name', 'name' + newNum );
```

Only the first child of each `newElem` is being selected, which is why only the first input element is being changed. What you want to do is select ALL the children that are input elements. Try this:

```
newElement.children('input').attr('id',$(this).attr('id') + newNum).attr('name',$(this).attr('name') + newNum);
```

Comment: Do you honestly expect `$(this).attr('id')` to work? Nice one on injecting duplicate id's into the DOM, create way to corrupt state.

Comment: @Raynos Huh? what are you talking about? The code I posted doesn't insert anything into the DOM. The `newNum` is being appended to each id to make them unique. Here's a simplified example. [http://jsfiddle.net/B7bgN/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/B7bgN/2/)

Comment: Did you even look at the id's of the inputs in your example? As mentioned you injected duplicate id's into the DOM.

Comment: @Raynos new working fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/B7bgN/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/B7bgN/10/)

Comment: @BrianGlaz your fiddle seems to work, but I'm having a hard time extrapolating that to my current code.  Can you help?

Comment: Sure, how can I help? Basically you call the clone function passing it whatever element you want to copy.

Comment: @BrianGlaz So based on your suggestions, I changed the code to: `newElement.children('input').attr('id',$(this).attr('id') + newNum).attr('name',$(this).attr('name') + newNum);` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.  Is this the same thing you are posting in your fiddle?

Comment: Check out the fiddle in the second comment (the link that ends in /10). There was a problem with my original one, so I corrected it. The code is a bit different then what you have above. http://jsfiddle.net/B7bgN/10/

Answer (score 1):

```
var cloneEl = (function () {
    var counter = 1;

    return function cloneEl(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById("container");
        var clone = el.cloneNode(true);

        clone.id = el.id+counter;
        [].forEach.call(clone.children, function (node, key) {
             var oldNode = el.children[key];
             node.id = oldNode.id+counter;
             node.name = oldNode.id+counter;
        });

        counter++;
        return clone;
    };
})();
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tKgMm/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I do: if you have multiple layers of div, tables (like me), you have to change the code provided by Brian Glaz from newElem.children to newElem.find. Here is his fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B7bgN/10/

All I did was change one word. From children to find. (Children will only traverse one level while find will get descendants of each element.

http://jsfiddle.net/the7th/sSS3c/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                                    var newNum = 1;
                                    cloneMe = function (el) {
                                        var newElem = el.clone().attr('class', 'firstrow' + newNum).insertAfter(".firstrow0");

                                        newElem.find('input').each(function (index, elem) {
                                            $(elem).attr('id', $(elem).attr('id') + newNum).attr('name', $(elem).attr('name') + newNum);
                                        });
                                        if (newNum == 2) {
                                            $("#cloneb").hide();
                                        };
                                        newNum++;
                                    };
                                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Though not a solution to the OP question, I found [**Jquery Form Clone Plugin**](http://abbasharoon.me/jquery-form-clone-plugin-form-cloning-in-6-easy-steps/) to be quite helpful. Its has everything preset, index, nested forms, controls and even callbacks like beforeAdd, after add etc. I mentioned it because when searching for a jQuery's solution, I ended up here. So I thought it might help others searching for jQuery's solution for cloning forms